# Filter collapse div and highlight current link through data-filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I filter the content of a div using data-filter and highlight current link at same time?

In this example the 'Item A' should be loaded as current item. The current item should have the `text-bold` class.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/3e38xmpn/1/)**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-list">
        <a class="menu-list-link js-menu-list-link" href="#" data-filter="1">Item A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list js-menu-list">
        <a class="menu-list-link js-menu-list-link" href="#" data-filter="2">Item B</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list">
        <a class="menu-list-link js-menu-list-link" href="#" data-filter="3">Item C</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If it's on load, why not add that class to the DOM itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code:-

```
$(function(){
    //this is for first page load
   $('a[data-filter="1"]').addClass('text-bold');
   filter(1);

   //when click on anchor tag
    $('.menu-list a').click(function(){  
        $('.menu-list a').removeClass('text-bold');
        $(this).addClass('text-bold');
        var data=$(this).data('filter');
        filter(data);
    });
});
```

and create a function:-

```
function filter(filter){
 $('.container [data-filter]').hide();
 $('.container [data-filter="'+filter+'"]').show();
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3e38xmpn/2/)

Comment: @brunodd happy to help you :)